# Building form dynamically from drop down menu selection

Tags: php, javascript, forms, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I would like to be able to dynamically add rows to a form (I have now included the form below) using a drop down menu.  I presume this would be a javascript function, but I'm not sure.

My idea is that all that would show on the page initially is a drop down menu which defaults to '1', and one row of the form with a few fields, such as name, email, age, etc.  The user is asked to select a number from the drop down menu, and then whatever number is selected, rows will be added to the form to match this number.

As an (important) aside, once the form has been completed I want to be able to submit the information in the form via email using PHP, and I wonder whether each input field would need to have a unique ID to pass to the PHP page that generates the email.  I mention this in case it needs to be taken into consideration in the method that is used to add rows to the table.

I'd be grateful for any help in getting going with this.

Thanks,

Nick

Form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST">
<label>Please select the number of people you are booking for:</label>
<select id="myDropDown">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select><br/><br />
<label>name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<label>email:</label> <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to be able to dynamically
>   add rows to a form using a drop down
>   menu. I presume this would be a
>   javascript function, but I'm not sure.

Yes, it would be easiest to do it in JavaScript. Pick a good toolkit like jQuery for helping you navigate and modify the DOM. Here's a simple skeleton:

```
$(function() {
    var myForm = $("#myForm");
    $("#myDropDown").select(function() {
        var selected = $("option:selected", this).val();
        $("<input/>")
            .attr("type", "text")
            .attr("name", selected)
            .attr("id", selected)
            .appendTo( myForm );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I have added jQuery, and started to build a form. I am not sure how to link the script and the form up though. I have now included the form in my original post. Basically I am trying to add an extra row with name and email fields. At the moment nothing is getting added when I select a number from the drop down menu.  Also, I have worked out that I don't need different name values for each row, as I can pass each input as an array to the PHP that generates the email.

Comment: Can anyone else help out with getting the form to link up with the drop down menu?  Thanks, Nick

Comment: Not sure if you got this figured out, but I would look into cgi scripting.  Basically your php code would print out the html/javascript every time the script is loaded. The javascript portion takes care of adding the forms and once submit is hit, the page reloads with the selections saved in your environment in the query_string, available for your use. That's one way your script would link up with the form (ie. php print statements)

Answer (score 0):

I think forms need unique names for post not id.

loop over the number selected, foreach one do this.

```
var newInput = document.createElement("input");
newInput.Name = "Unique name to form"
newInput.Type = "text" // or whatever

document.getElementById("formId").appendChild(newInput);
```

note that it could be done easier with jQuery possibly but this will work with the built in js function.